# How to consolidate cucumber reports generated by cucumber-jvm-parallel plugin

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-junit, extentreports

We are using cucumber-jvm-parallel plugin for automatic cucumber runners generation.

It generates cucumber report in folders like- 1,2,3 based on number of runners.
a) I would like to merge these reports into one.
b) as suggested on below link, I have configured a set-up, but its not generating extent report
https://github.com/temyers/cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin/tree/master/src/it/junit/extents-report

c) Jenkins is also unable to publish a report, for any of the runner
I tried

```
**/*.json 
/target/cucumber-parallel/**/*.json
/target/cucumber-parallel/*.json
/target/*.json
/target/**.json
```

Please suggest
Thanks

Comment: You can use this plugin which will provide you the desired results::  https://github.com/email2vimalraj/CucumberExtentReporter. It allows parallel report generation with extent reports and also has support for extentx server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Donut Report](http://donut.report/).

It has both a Maven plugin and Jenkins plugin available, and is able to combine multiple Cucumber json reports.  It can also report on unit test results to provide a unified report of your test coverage.

Comment: Kindly check below issue, which I have started facing on Donut report, recently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48116087/donut-report-donut-maven-plugin-is-not-getting-generated-when-some-of-the-test

Comment: Kindly request you to take a look at below issue:  Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48116087/donut-report-donut-maven-plugin-is-not-getting-generated-when-some-of-the-test